# PreferenceActivity do something when preference are changed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have preference xml and following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DO SOMETHING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I want to get notified over toast message, when one or more preferences are changed. I think upper code should work, but for some reason it doesn't.

I have for example CheckBoxPreference in my xml file. And when I check or uncheck CheckBox I want to be notified.

Comment: you could try extending the `SharedPreerences` class and adding the functionality manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the listener like this for example:

```
       PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).
                                 registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

or, if You don´t use the default shared preferences, You have to get Your prefs and then register them:

```
       SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("your_shared_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: How do you mean if i'm not using default sheared preferences? I use xml file which I had write by myself.

Comment: You can set sharedPreferences in different ways. Either You use the default shared preferences (like I guess Yu do it) or You give some "id" for the preferences like shown in the second part of my answer. But don´t be confused, I think the first way is what You do.

Answer (score 1):

You should register to listen to the shared preference changes:

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

         getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
```